# DataSet sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sorting, dataset

In `DataTable` I could sorting with

```
 dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "SortField DESC";
```

I'm getting a `DataSet` from database, I was wondering could I do a sorting on the `DataSet` like how I do it in `DataTable`.

Comment: I think you must see a link.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b51xae2y%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can still access the DataTable from the the data set as follows,

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort =" criterian";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which is descending order or what?

Comment: @MdAslam e.g. `"Fieldname DESC"` or `"Fieldname"` (ASC is default)

Answer (score 8):

```
DataView view = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

view.Sort = "SortField DESC";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ay5y4w0(v=vs.71).aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/netfxbcl/thread/adbd95cd-49d1-483d-b2b2-4b696a66e9a6

Answer (score 4):

Access the `DataTable` from the the `DataSet` as follows,

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "SortField DESC";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

For advanced sorting needs you might want to use LINQ like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-binding-and-linq-to-dataset). Basically it allows creating a DataView from a LINQ query using the [System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsDataFiew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907985(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method.

Alternatively if you are OK with (or maybe even prefer) using an IEnumerable
you could use the [System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) extension method. For example:

```
var enumerable = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                 .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("ColumnName")
                 .ThenByDescending(x => x.Field<int?>("OtherColumnName")??0);
```

Comment: You can also add chain a `CopyToDataTable()` to directly get a `DataTable` you can work with (if you want to add it to a new `DataSet` or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

From tha DataSet object, you can access all the DataTable to intract with.

Try this:

```
DataDet.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "sort criteria";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 DataSet fileTransferDetail = null;//Data to be sorted.
 DataSet result = null;//Declare a dataSet to be filled.

//Sort data.
fileTransferDetail.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "ID DESC";
//Store in new Dataset
result.Tables.Add(fileTransferDetail.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.Sort=value;
```