# Sorting DataSet being fed by SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sorting, dataset

I'm fetching data via a query being run by a `SqlDataAdapter` let's call `da` and filling my `DataSet`, we'll call `ds` with what is returned by `da`. I'm then returning this `ds` from my function but before it's returned I'd like it sorted by a particular column that's part of my `da`.

### Code

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
da.fill(ds);
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "date DESC";
ds1.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable());

return ds1;
```

However, when I go to view the results they're still not being sorted by the date in descending order.

**EDIT** 
I've referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029823/dataset-sorting) and didn't have any luck.

Comment: What is the output of ds1.Tables[0].Columns["date"].DataType.ToString()?

Comment: I get `System.String`.

Comment: That is why you cannot see the sorted output. The system is sorting that column as String.

Answer (score 0):

Your column type is String and you are probably expecting a date sort. This is where you think it is going wrong. It is sorting it as a string column. The code you have shown will work well if the Data Type is correct i.e. DateTime or long

Comment: So I could cast the string as a DateTime and then try sorting that, right?

Comment: In your query you mean?

Comment: I can't cast them in my dataset?

Comment: I don't think so. Because your dataset has already determined it to be a Column of type String. When it gets into your DataSet, it should have been of type DateTime. Look at this answer.. it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572685/sort-string-items-in-a-datatable-as-int-using-c-sharp